Vue transition with black background for smooth dimming on route changes
I'm trying to find a way to change the vue-transition background-color, so that it naturally fades-in and out with a dark background when changing the route? For example, right now I have background-color: blue set on body, and everytime I change the route, I can see the blue background, which looks weird. I want to make it look like a slightshow with a black background. But at the same time I don't want to set background-color: black on body, I just want the transition to be black, not my page background.
// css
body {
    background-color: blue;
}

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 0.4s linear;
}
.fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
}

// template
<RouterView #="{ Component }">
    <Transition mode="out-in" name="fade">
        <component :is="Component" :key="route.path" />
    </Transition>
</RouterView>

Looking for a possible solution.
